# How to split a string by triple dots or horizontal ellipsis

Tags: java, split, delimiter

I am facing problems when trying to split a String by "..."

```
    String text ="Here…It is safer.";
```

I tried:

```
String [] output = text.split("[\\...]");
String [] output = text.split("\\.");
```

and many others, but I haven't found the solution yet.

I know that the question is very simple, but I will be happy If somebody can explain how should I make it work.

Comment: Try `text.split("\\.{2,}|…")`.

Answer (score 5):

Regex for matching three dots is `\\.{3}` or `\\.\\.\\.` or `[.][.][.]` or `\\Q...\\E`.

Both `[\\...]` and `\\.` match a single dot, because repeated characters inside a character class are treated as a single character.

Horizontal ellipsis is a different character. It is not a metacharacter in regex language, so it can be matched directly with no escaping:

```
String [] output = text.split("…");
```

Comment: Or `.split("…|\\Q...\\E")`

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks - I completely forgot about an ability to escape blocks of regexes "wholesale".

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use

```java
String[] chunks = text.split("…|\\.{3}");
```

To also remove the enclosing whitespace:

```java
String[] chunks = text.split("\\s*(?:…|\\.{3})\\s*");
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y91XIm/1).

If you need to make sure the triple dots are NOT enclosed with other dot chars, you can add lookarounds:

```java
String[] chunks = text.split("\\s*(?:…|(?<!\\.)\\.{3}(?!\\.))\\s*");
```

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:...)` - a non-capturing group
- `…` - an ellipsis
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\.)`  - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a dot char immediately to the left of the current location
- `\.{3}` - triple dots
- `(?!\.)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a dot char immediately to the right of the current location.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/b5rGMQ):

```java
String text = "Here…It is safer... The end.";
String[] chunks = text.split("\\s*(?:…|\\.{3})\\s*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chunks));
// => [Here, It is safer, The end.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex for multiple dots would be:

```
(\.)*
```

Java would require something like this if I remember correct:

```
(\\.)*
```

Edit: Just noticed you asked for triple dot only. Since there is a correct answer already I'm going to leave this here just in case.